# Flutterwave bill payment API integration

Tags: php, api, flutterwave

does anyone know how I can charge a customer through his/her card for Bill payments with flutterwave api

Comment: to answer the question: yes; now if you want some help with code, paste some example please.

Comment: $url = 'https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/bills';
   $body = [
        "country" => "NG",
   "customer" => "+2348128988364",
   "amount" => 200,
   "recurrence" => "ONCE",
   "type" => "AIRTIME",
   "reference" => "08060612315"
       ];
      $body = wp_json_encode($body);
   $args = array(
       'method' => 'POST',
   'headers' => array(
       'Authorization' => 'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
      
  'body' => $body
   
 );


 
  $response = wp_remote_post($url, $args);
  }

Comment: this just charges the customer from my flutterwave dashboard balance @ ha100

Comment: please edit your original post and indent the code for better readability in there. nobody will take the time to answer your question like this

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However, the request payload differs based on the bill payment type and the biller.

The general flow is as below:

1. Get the biller details.
2. Make the bill payment.
3. Verify the status of the bill

Here are the links to the docs for the [billers](https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference#get-bill-categories), [initiating the payment](https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference#create-a-bill-payment) and [verifying its status](https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference#get-status-of-a-bill-payment).

Comment: One other important aspect of bill payments is prefunding. Funds for the payments are usually debited from your position before they can be processed successfully.